# Java: Validating attribute before storing to the DDC

Tags: java

I am trying to validate input from users.
If a user enters firstName, the program will validate to ensure the firstName is not null or an empty String before going to the last`enter code here`Name.
Could you help me a way to solve the problem?
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

```
public class implementation{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //studentTesting student=new studentTesting("asd","asd");
        // getting first name and last name. Make sure each value is valid before moving to another attribute.
        boolean allValid=false;
        do {
            try {
                Student1 student=new Student1(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter first name"),JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter lastname"));
                allValid=true;
            }catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
            }
        }while(!allValid);
    }
}
class Student1 {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Student1(String firstName, String lastName) {
        if(firstName==null || firstName.equals(""))
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("first name Error");
        }
        if(lastName==null || lastName.equals(""))
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("last name Error");
        }
        this.lastName=lastName;
        this.firstName=firstName;



    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        if(lastName==null || lastName.equals(""))
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("last name Error");
        }
        this.lastName=lastName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        if(firstName==null || firstName.equals(""))
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("first name Error");
        }
        this.firstName=firstName;
    }


}
```

Comment: What's the problem exactly? This code doesn't work?

Comment: It works. I check it, but it does not work as i expect    the problem is. The program will pop up a window to let student enter first name, and check the first name to make sure it valid before a student can enter lastname. if there is an error in firstname, an error will print out to let the student know.